# Does Oracle SQL Developer require a dedicated git repository?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to version an sql db in Oracle Developer but I do not want to create a new git repository but instead use a directory in an existing project to version the files. Is this possible?

Comment: Existing project...what kind of project? We have a git and subversion client built in. Or you can just save your work in local files with no source control.

Comment: In my case there are already a number of visual studio projects in the repository. I want to version the sql scripts in that same repo. I see that I can clone or initialize a repo but what if the repo is already cloned on my drive (and already contains other stuff)?

Comment: this isn't an oracle question, it's about managing your source control projects, adding/merging things to an existing project is of course possible

Comment: That answers my question then. What is the initial step in OSD to dump the sql schema into a directory in my repo (or any directory on my disk)?

Comment: Search the site, and you would find this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52599276/1156452

Comment: Perfect, just the info I was looking for.